# How can I move Salesforce projects to GitHub repository?

Tags: github

I wanted to move Salesforce metadata to Github repo.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is quite broad. I suggest you Google "salesforce git" and pick items from the results that are relevant to your specific requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in general you want this:

First, use the Salesforce IDE, create a new Force.com project, provide your credentials and select all the components that you want to sync to your PC. You now have all the necessary metadata on your local system.

Second, initialize a GIT repository on the IDE's project folder in the workspace. Add all the files to the repo and commit. All files are now in GIT, and changes can be tracked.

Third, add the Github remote URL and push. You now have your repo on Github.

Comment: Thank you so much Willem Mulder. 
So I got my package in Eclipse.
After I initialise the path using $ cd path/to/Eclipse-workspace-folder, how can I add package.xml file to GitHub repository.

for example: $ gid add, which command I should use.

I am little bit confused. Kindly let me know If I understood correctly.

Comment: $ git Add .

Then $ commit -m 'first commit!'

Then push it up to Github. But there's plenty of documentation on the internet on Git. Please upvote and/or accept this answer if it helped you!